# Cannot switch to virtual consoles with Ctrl Alt Fx

Tags: 18.04, tty, virtual-console

I have recently installed Kubuntu 18.04 on a Dell XPS 13 9370. I cannot switch from the GUI to any virtual console using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fx</kbd> for any x=1,2,... (or any key combination I can discover). I have never had a Linux system with this property. I would be grateful for any information on how to fix this.

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem. I really appreciate the answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you use a laptop, <kbd>Fn</kbd>-lock is one possibility. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.

If that works and you want to turn off <kbd>Fn</kbd>-lock, look for the lock icon in the upper row of the keyboard and press <kbd>Fn</kbd>+that key. If you can't find one, try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

First, edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` uncommenting the first two lines:

```
NAutoVTs=6
ReserveVT=6
```

then execute

```
sudo chvt <vt_number>
```

from any terminal emulator.
Personally I didn't manage to make hotkeys work in the GUI, but they work while using other virtual terminals.